# Raspberry Pi 2 b+ + windows 10

Tags: windows

So my dad bought this program: http://dslrbooth.com/ will I be able to run it on the raspberry pi 2 b+ running windows 10, the main reason i ask this is because last time we did this we used my Microsoft surface pro 2 and it overheated (from being in the sun, plus it is pure black which didn't help it staying cool) and melted the CPU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to run dslrBooth on the Raspberry Pi.  While MS is in fact releasing an ARM 7 variant of Windows 10, the software it runs will still need to compiled for the ARM 7 architecture.  dslrBooth has states on it's requirement page that it requires Direct X 9 to run, and since it doesn't specify any systems that have an ARM processor for the core application, I'm assuming it requires an x86 processor as well.

Comment: ok thanks, also is there a way i could modify it to do that

Comment: No, there isn't a program that can be ported.  Since both the program and it's requirements are x86 based and closed source, there's no way to make it work on an ARM processor.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to run any Windows specific software on a B+ because there will never be a version of Windows for the B+.

The A, B, A+, and B+ models use an [ARMv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) processor.  The Pi 2 is different from these in that it uses an ARMv7 processor.  ARMv7 is much more common as it is widely used on mobile phones, etc., hence it is not a great stretch for MS to release a version for the Pi 2 only, although [they have not done so yet](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/featured/raspberrypi2support).

If you are thinking of buying a pi for a purpose requiring Windows, I would wait until it is released to see if what you want to do is feasible, since it may not have all the features of the regular version.

Comment: I already know that it wont work on ARMv6 pi boards and only on the new pi board

Comment: Sorry -- I saw "B+" and just noticed you wrote "B+ 2".   I think it's just "Pi 2" but the form factor is the same as the B+.  The foundation made all this a little confusing IMO.  Anyway, if you are looking to run a Windows GUI, don't hold your breath.

Comment: ok thanks, that sucks because of my surface incident i realy wanted to run it on something else, also i am really hating MS right now my surface that i mentioned in my first post we took it back to them to get it fixed and they said it would take 3 to 4 weeks to fix, the worst part about it is that a project that i was working on for school is still on my desktop and i put over 10 hours into it, and there is a posibility that i may not get my documents back.

Comment: That does suck.  We all -- or many of us, me included -- learn this the hard way: You have have to back your stuff up.  This isn't simple and easy no matter how you do it until you get used to doing it.  Backing it up a few different ways is a good idea too, "the cloud" (e.g. Dropbox) and a USB thumb drive being two.   It may take a few minutes but it is not 10 hours ;\

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. In addition to being a different architecture, there is no GUI in the RasPi Win10. It's pretty much just a shell. Any program that needs the GUI (e.g: Office, and probably DSLRBOOTH) cannot run.